# PHP Contact Form not sending for some reason

Tags: php, forms, contacts

I've edited a simple contact form downloaded off the internet, I'm not a big PHP guy so i've most likely done something wrong.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
/*
This first bit sets the email address that you want the form to be submitted to.
You will need to change this value to a valid email address that you can access.
*/
$webmaster_email = "xxxxxxxx@me.com"; /* ENTER EMAIL ADDRESS TO THE LEFT INSIDE THE QUOTES */

/*
This bit sets the URLs of the supporting pages.
If you change the names of any of the pages, you will need to change the values here.
*/
$feedback_page = "index.html";
$error_page = "index.html";
$thankyou_page = "index.html";

/*
This next bit loads the form field data into variables.
If you add a form field, you will need to add it here.
*/
$name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
$company = $_REQUEST['company'] ;
$phone = $_REQUEST['phone'] ;
$email_address = $_REQUEST['email_address'] ;
$comments = $_REQUEST['message'] ;

/*
The following function checks for email injection.
Specifically, it checks for carriage returns - typically used by spammers to inject a CC list.
*/
function isInjected($str) {
    $injections = array('(\n+)',
    '(\r+)',
    '(\t+)',
    '(%0A+)',
    '(%0D+)',
    '(%08+)',
    '(%09+)'
);
$inject = join('|', $injections);
$inject = "/$inject/i";
if(preg_match($inject,$str)) {
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
}

// If the user tries to access this script directly, redirect them to the feedback form,
if (!isset($_REQUEST['email_address'])) {
header( "Location: $feedback_page" );
}

// If the form fields are empty, redirect to the error page.
elseif (empty($email_address) || empty($comments)) {
    header( "Location: $error_page" );
}

// If email injection is detected, redirect to the error page.
elseif ( isInjected($email_address) ) {
    header( "Location: $error_page" );
}

// If we passed all previous tests, send the email then redirect to the thank you page.
else {
    mail( "$webmaster_email", "CDR-Print Enquiry",  
  "Name: $name", "Company: $company", "Phone: $phone", "From: $email_address", "Message: $comments"  );
header( "Location: $thankyou_page" );
}
?>
```

Comment: Don't just post a wall of code. Include details: What is wrong? eg: what do you expect it to do, and what does it actually do? Are there any errors? What are the error messages, if any?

Comment: I strongly suggest starting [here](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php).

Answer (score 3):

Mail function can take up to 5 arguments, in your case it's taking 7 and most of them don't make sense:

```
mail( "$webmaster_email", "CDR-Print Enquiry", "Name: $name", "Company: $company", "Phone: $phone", "From: $email_address", "Message: $comments");
```

Please check the [mail manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) to see how your script should work, basically you need to do it like this:

```
mail('person@example.com', 'My Subject', $message);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your mail function

It should be something like this:

```
$message = 'Name: $name, Company: $company Phone: $phone From: $email_address Message: $comments'

mail( "$webmaster_email", "CDR-Print Enquiry", $message);
```

Please, check [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) link so you can have a better understanding about mail function.

Comment: In regards to Gerep, I've changed my code to the following but it still isn't working 

http://pastie.org/pastes/3046850/text

Sorry for making this awesome, but I have very little, well no knowledge of PHP but desperately need to incorporate a contact form

Comment: try this: $message = 'Name: '.$name.', Company: '.$company.', Phone: '.$phone.', From: '.$email_address.', Message: '.$comments

Answer (score 0):

Is it giving some error? Or just not sending the mail? You can check if the `mail` function was successful or not by running an `if` on it since `mail` returns a boolean value of it's success.